# Verificar saldo negativo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Via JavaScript ou Jquery, preciso checar se existe algum saldo negativo.
Se tiver saldo negativo, então:
var SALDO_DISPONIVEL = 0
senão:
var SALDO_DISPONIVEL = 1

Segue abaixo o fonte html:

```html
 <html> 
 <head> 
  <title>Histórico das Aprovações</title> 
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'> 
  <style type='text/css'> 
   table { 
    table-layout: fixed; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   } 
  
   th { 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
    background-color: #009fef; 
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
   } 
  
   td { 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
   } 
  
   .centro { 
    text-align: center; 
   } 
  
   .cinzaClaro { 
    background-color: #CACACA; 
   } 
  
   .cinzaEscuro { 
    background-color: #EBEBEB; 
   } 
  </style> 
 </head> 
 <body style='text-align: center; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 3px;'> 
  <table> 
   <thead> 
    <tr> 
     <th style='width: 100px;'>Material</th> 
     <th style='width: 100px;'>Verba Total</th> 
     <th style='width: 100px;'>Saldo Disponível</th> 
    </tr> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody> 
    <tr class='cinzaEscuro'> 
     <td class='centro'>210</td> 
     <td class='centro'>76.045,00</td> 
     <td id='saldo' class='centro'>45.555,00</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class='cinzaClaro'> 
     <td class='centro'>211</td> 
     <td class='centro'>100,00</td> 
     <td id='saldo' class='centro'>80,00</td> 
    </tr> 
   </tbody> 
  </table> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Como você sabe qual é o valor dando negativo? não faltou dizer qual é a conta !

Comment: Em outras palavras, se tiver qualquer <td id='saldo'> que seja negativo a variável SALDO_DISPONIVEL deve ser igual a 0.
Nesse exemplo do HTML não existe nenhum saldo negativo, então a variável SALDO_DISPONIVEL deve ser 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem simples usando somente javascript...
Pega todos os elementos com classe .saldo, verifica se tem algum negativo, se tiver marca 0. senão fica 1.

PS: Lembra de evitar duplicar ids na página, id deve ser único. Nesse caso o melhor é utilizar uma classe para identificar os itens já que são vários.

Edit: tinha feito parseInt, alterei código para parseFloat :D

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var saldos = document.querySelectorAll('.saldo');
  var output = document.getElementById('disponivel');
  
  var saida = 1;
  let innerValue;
  for(let k of saldos) {
    innerValue = k.innerHTML.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
    if(parseFloat(innerValue) < 0) {
      saida = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  output.innerHTML = "SALDO DISPONIVEL: " + saida;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Histórico das Aprovações</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>
  <style type='text/css'>
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      background-color: #009fef;
      padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
    
    td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
    
    .centro {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .cinzaClaro {
      background-color: #CACACA;
    }
    
    .cinzaEscuro {
      background-color: #EBEBEB;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style='text-align: center; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 3px;'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Material</th>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Verba Total</th>
        <th style='width: 100px;'>Saldo Disponível</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class='cinzaEscuro'>
        <td class='centro'>210</td>
        <td class='centro'>76.045,00</td>
        <td class='centro saldo'>45.555,00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='cinzaClaro'>
        <td class='centro'>211</td>
        <td class='centro'>100,00</td>
        <td class='centro saldo'>80,00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <p id="disponivel"></p>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo!
Eu li todas as respostas, mas essa serviu como uma LUVA!
Era disso que eu precisava!

Comment: @Y.Menon Obrigado amigo, fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Selecione todos os últimos `tds` da tabela e faça um laço `for` verificando se o valor é menor que `0`.

Mas é preciso tratar os valores antes da verificação, tirar os pontos que separam o milhar e em seguida substituir a vírgula por ponto, já que o JavaScript considera o "ponto" o separador de decimais.

O código inicia o `SALDO_DISPONIVEL` com valor `1`, e o `for` vai verificando *linha por linha* e caso um dos valores seja menor do que zero, ele altera o valor da variável `SALDO_DISPONIVEL` para `0` e interrompe o loop.

```js
$(function(){
   var tds =  $("table tbody tr td:last-child"),
       SALDO_DISPONIVEL = 1;
   
   for(var x=0; x<tds.length; x++){
      var valor = $(tds[x]).text().replace(".","").replace(",",".");
      if(parseFloat(valor) < 0){ SALDO_DISPONIVEL = 0; break; }
   }
   
   console.log("Saldo disponível = "+SALDO_DISPONIVEL);
});
```

```css
table { 
   table-layout: fixed; 
   border-collapse: collapse; 
} 

th { 
   border: 1px solid #000; 
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 0.8em; 
   background-color: #009fef; 
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
} 

td { 
   border: 1px solid #000; 
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 0.8em; 
   padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
} 

.centro { 
   text-align: center; 
} 

.cinzaClaro { 
   background-color: #CACACA; 
} 

.cinzaEscuro { 
   background-color: #EBEBEB; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
   <thead> 
      <tr> 
         <th style='width: 100px;'>Material</th> 
         <th style='width: 100px;'>Verba Total</th> 
         <th style='width: 100px;'>Saldo Disponível</th> 
      </tr> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody> 
      <tr class='cinzaEscuro'> 
         <td class='centro'>210</td> 
         <td class='centro'>76.045,00</td> 
         <td id='saldo' class='centro'>45.555,00</td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class='cinzaClaro'> 
         <td class='centro'>211</td> 
         <td class='centro'>100,00</td> 
         <td id='saldo' class='centro'>80,00</td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class='cinzaEscuro'> 
         <td class='centro'>211</td> 
         <td class='centro'>100,00</td> 
         <td id='saldo' class='centro'>-80,00</td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr class='cinzaClaro'> 
         <td class='centro'>211</td> 
         <td class='centro'>100,00</td> 
         <td id='saldo' class='centro'>80,00</td> 
      </tr> 
   </tbody> 
</table>
```